# Помогите разобраться в синтаксисе

Tags: c#

```
private class ListNode
      {
          public int Data = 0;

          public ListNode Next = null;

        public ListNode(int data, ListNode next)
        {
            Data = data;
            Next = next;
        }
    }

    private ListNode Head = null;
    private ListNode Tail = null;

    public void Print()
    {
        ListNode p = Head;
        while (p != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Data);
            p = p.Next;
        }
    }
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в методе Print "p" - это локальная ссылочная переменная, которая ссылается на главный элемент списка? (именно в первой строке метода)

Comment: да. "главный" - в смысле, первый

Comment: в таком случае, как в 3-й строке этого же метода можно возвратить переменную Data типа int, ведь "p" - это локальная переменная только ссылочная типа, т.е. для ссылок?

Comment: @MartinEden в 3ей строке вы обращаетесь по ссылке к объекту p и к его полю Data.

Comment: Но ссылка-то эта указывает на объект типа `ListNode`, у которого есть `Data`

Comment: тогда в четвёртой строке объекту "p" присваивается ссылка на этот же объект, но к его другому ссылочному полю Next? т.е. объект "p" ссылается по ссылке два раза: сначала к полю Data, а затем к ссылке Next?

Comment: но не одновременно :)

Answer (score 1):

Класс ListNode имеет поле для хранения данных  и ссылку на следующий элемент этого же типа. В методе Print происходит ничто иное как обход списка: в локальную переменную р записывается ссылка на "голову" списка, далее в цикле в консоль выводятся данные текущего элемента, а переменной р присваивается указатель на следующий элемент списка. Операция повторяется до тех пор, пока не закончатся элементы.

Если же какой-то элемент присутствует в списке дважды, цикл никогда не закончится - программа будет бесконечно бегать по кругу. Чтобы этого избежать следует каким-то образом помечать посещенные узлы: либо добавив свойство Visited к ListNode, либо добавляя каждый посещенный элемент в отдельную коллекцию (HashSet). При повторном посешении вершины цикл прерывается.